# A section is not moving up according to the layout

Tags: html, css

When I shrink the browser horizontally, I need the 'slide' element to shrink as the image does, so the section 'content' can move up right below the image position. I need the html code to remain as it is now.

```css
 

#body{
    background:red;
    height:500px; 
}
#slide{
 width:100%;
 display:flex;
 position:relative;
 height:500px;
 overflow:hidden;
 background:red;
}
#videoSlide{
 position:absolute; 
 max-width:100%;  
 z-index:0;
 transform: translateY(-20%); 
}
#videoSlide img{
 width:100%;
}
#content{
 width:100%;
 height:50px;
 background:yellow;
}
```

```html
  
   
<html>
<head>
 <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Patua+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
 <header>  
 </header>
 <section id="body"> 
  <section id="slide">
   <div id="videoSlide">
    <img src="https://images2.alphacoders.com/209/209140.jpg"/>
   </div>    
  </section>
  <section id="content">   
  </section>
 </section>
 <footer>
 </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please try to include only code related to your issue. There is a lot of extra stuff here for people to have to pick through.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I edited the code placing only what I think relevant.

Comment: I've edited your question by posting your code as a snippet that will additionally demonstrate the output of your code (like a sandbox).

Comment: Oh that is great!, thanks for the help and tip.

Comment: In order to snippet function can show the website correctly, I had to put all code again.

Comment: Using the responsive design mode of [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Responsive_Design_Mode) or [Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/iterate/device-mode/?hl=en) (see links), identify at what screen width (in pixels) the problem occurs. Specifics like this will help myself and others understand your question.

Comment: I was reviewing in depth my problem, so I updated my question with new information.